# Starting HTML Template when app loads

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Noob question here. I am very new to using angular and ionic. I am building an app for a course and I started by using a tutorial and I have just been changing things until it becomes the app I want.

I want to change the initial html page that gets loaded when you run the app. Where do I set this?

Sorry! I am aware that this is probably super obvious but I can't seem to figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the approach you are taking on design flow of your application. You can use state and define templates folder and assign each template(.html file) to specific view. for example according to this tutorial of Ionic 
http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/platform-customization/dynamic-templates.html

you can have this simplified version in you app.js file

`.state('app.main', {
    url: '/main',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/main.html',
        controller : 'mainCtrl'
      }
    }
  })`

In this case you can edit you html in main.html and mainCtrl is the controller assigned to this template.

Answer (score 0):

**Ionic2**

It would be better to share some code. But I will try to answer the question as I got it.

If you created your app with `ionic-cli` then you will find in the file `app.component.ts`  the class `MyApp`. There is a line where the `rootPage` is set. All you need to do is to change the value of the `rootPage` to the **Class** of the page you want to open when your app starts.

```
rootPage: any = LoginPage;
```

Please remember to do the following:

1. Import the target page in the `app.component.ts`.
2. Add the page to the `declarations` and `entryComponents`  in the `NgModule` decoration in the file `app.module.ts`